# How to count news in some headnig if this heading has a lot of subheadings

Tags: sql, select

I have some database.

Schema of my database
https://www.dropbox.com/s/57todvdrwnl9ooe/2222.jpg

My database has next structure: 1. News table with columns (Id , Name , Id_Heading) 2. Heading/Subheading table (Id , Name) 3. Table of references between heading and subheading (Id_Heading , Id_Subheading) bouth Id takes from Heading/Subheading table

For example I have heading - "Music" (with id = 1) and subheading "Industrial" (with id = 2), "Punk" (with id = 3) and etc. Also I have table News with ID_of_news , Name_of_news and ID_of_Heading. For Example: 1 (Some Name) 2. Other news are 2 (Some name) 3.... and more on.

I want to get a table with two columns "name" or "ID" of Heading and how many "News" are in this Heading

I tried it with the following query

```
 SELECT COUNT(n.Id) as Test, heading.Name
FROM [Heading\Subheading] heading
    INNER JOIN [Relationship_Heading] tf ON tf.Id_Heading = heading.Id
    LEFT JOIN [Heading\Subheading] subheading ON subheading.Id = tf.Id_Subheading
    LEFT JOIN News n ON subheading.Id = n.Id_Heading
    LEFT JOIN News n2 ON heading.Id = n2.Id_Heading
GROUP BY heading.Name
```

But this request gives me the quantity how many news in every subheading, but no in heading

Comment: Can you provide sample data and desired output to clarify what you are looking for?

Comment: Maybe add it to [sqlfiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com) with your attempt.

Comment: Judging by column names you are using SQL Server or MS Access. Why is your question tagged with `mysql`?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because the the data in the question (the image of the database schema) is no longer available, so there's no longer enough information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this:

```
SELECT COUNT(heading.Id_Heading) as Test, heading.Id_Heading
FROM [Heading\Subheading] heading
    INNER JOIN [Table References] tf ON tf.Id_Heading = heading.Id_Heading
    LEFT JOIN [Heading\Subheading] subheading ON subheading.id_Heading = tf.Id_Subeading
    LEFT JOIN News n ON subheading.id_Heading = n.Id_Heading
    LEFT JOIN News n2 ON heading.id_Heading = n2.Id_Heading
GROUP BY heading.Id_Heading
```

**UPDATE:** sorry, changed the inner join to left join, is that work as expected now?

Comment: Yes this is work, but it show quantity how many news in every Subheading, but i need how many news are in every Heading. Subheading is the child element of Heading, every Heading has more than 3 Subheading

Comment: is Id_Heading in News table can be either Id of Heading and Subheading, or is it always Id of Heading? If it is the first, then try add this: `INNER JOIN [Table References] tf ON tf.Id_Heading = n.Id_Heading` after the existing INNER JOIN above. how is that?

Comment: It always Id of Heading, but if Heading has Subheading it is Id of  Subheading

Comment: have you tried adding INNER JOIN to Table References between heading and subheading as i showed in the comment above? It should count only news in heading. If it still not working as you want, i think i missed something in your question

Comment: I added this, but now it count news in Heading which hasn't subheading, but I must count news include subheading, i'll try to do some picture

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/9lguxq6z0g6kyof/example.jpg

Comment: updated my answer, check it out..

Comment: It valid, but return empty table with 2 columns ID and test... :(

Comment: With LEFT JOIN it count quantity how many subheading in each heading, but it should count how many news in headings include subheading ....

Comment: Update code, now it count well, but ignores Headings that hasn't subheading, i think that need join

Comment: After adding some spikes like a empty reference into the table Heading, it work great, thank u